# Is there finitely generated module which has direct summand is not finitely generated?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit. Is there an example of a finitely generated $R$-module $M$ which has a direct summand $N$ not finitely generated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $N$ is a direct summand of $M$, say $M = N \oplus P$, then the map $n+p \mapsto n$ for $n \in N$ and $p \in P$ is a surjective homomorphism $M \to N$. Now, recall that an $R$-module $A$ is finitely generated if and only if there is a surjective homomorphism $R^k \to A$ for some positive integer $k$. Can you see now why there is no such example?